# A rare currency

Tags: meaning, word-usage

For example: When I am writing an article about friendship, and want to say it's difficult to find a good friend, it is possible to say it's like finding a rare currency today?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that we are not a writers workshop, nor a proofreading service. Please consult the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for a better understanding of how this site operates. The short answer is that *rare currency* is not a common expression; you may be thinking of  *[rare commodity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rare+currency%2C+rare+commodity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might mean 'like finding a rare *coin*.'

عملة can mean 'coin' or 'currency' in English. (Sorry if that is presumptuous--bas ismak howa arabi!)

Answer (score 0):

A currency is never rare, especially in its own country. You may want to use something like 'obsolete' instead of 'rare', indicating something that is no longer in use and hence can't be obtained easily.

Comment: So you mean that "a rare currency" is not an expression that can generally be used to describe a friendship?

Comment: What about $2 bills, those seem pretty rare to me even though they're currency in my country (the United States).

Comment: @sumelic The US Treasury reports 850M $2 bills in circulation.  This is much fewer than the 9.5B $1 bills, but the twos are hardly rare.  You need to hang around more at the two-dollar window at the track.  In any case, "currency" here refers to a type of money like Federal Reserve Notes.  When more than one type of currency are in circulation, Gresham's Law often guarantees that one of them will become rare.

Comment: Aren't we confusing 'currency' and 'coin/note in circulation' here? In the UK, the sovereign is a rare _form of currency_.

Answer (score 0):

**it is a rare currency today.**

sounds rather like

**it is a rare occurrence today**

> **occurrence:**  something that happens : the fact of happening or occurring - *[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occurrence)*

So, a rare occurrence is something that rarely happens. Is it possible this might have been intended in the original sentence?

Comment: Great.  Another DBDV.  And for a perfectly good answer.  "Finding a good friend is a rare occurrence" works and might explain the OP's somewhat odd locution.  The OP would have to say, of course, whether it's an apt substitute for him.

Comment: Thanks for the typo correction, ratty. Down vote, eh? ( I thought it was an interesting parallel: a possible eggcorn?).

Comment: You're welcome.  Yeah,  DBDV is my abbreviation for "Drive-by down-vote," a vote of disapproval by someone who doesn't have the courtesy to leave a comment of explanation.  I'm sure you know that if you click the "0" on your answer, you'll see the downvote, which happens to be balanced by an upvote. +1-1=0.  Yours is an interesting observation, putting all the discussion of currency in perspective.

Answer (score 0):

*Rare currency* is a collectible.

I think your sentence is okay, but I would omit "today".

Comment: So good friends are collectibles?  The grammar is fine, but the sentence isn't OK.

Comment: @deadrat - The OP seems to be of the opinion that good friends are hard to find, and worth collecting and holding on to, as an investment for the future.  Please help me understand what's bothering you about the sentence.

Comment: Collectibles include coins, stamps, and Samantha Eggar, but not friends.  Currency is a medium of exchange, something somewhat at odds with friendship.  This is a strange usage and as choster points out, is likely a mishearing of the idiom "rare commodity."

Comment: @deadrat - So could the OP fix it by replacing *currency* with *commodity*?

Comment: "A good friend is a rare commodity" does it for me, but the OP would have to say if that metaphor works for him.  See Margana's answer below for an alternative.